# Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'markt'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code snippet that does not compile:

```
struct TabBar: View {
    
    @Binding var tappedItem: TabBarItem = .markt
    
    private let cartIcon = "cart.circle"
    private let interestIcon = "person.crop.square.filled.and.at.rectangle"
    private let walletIcon = "creditcard.circle"
    private let fillIcon = "fill"
    
    var body: some View {
        

        
        VStack {
            
            Divider().frame(height: 1)
                .overlay(Color.primaryColor)
                
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: cartIcon)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primaryColor)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: interestIcon)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primaryColor)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: walletIcon)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primaryColor)
            }.padding(.horizontal, 40)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
        }
        
           
    }
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'markt'
```

I know I have to remove the initialisation to get it compiled. However, I would like to understand why the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the property is not `TabBarItem`, it is `Binding<TabBarItem>` which has no value `.markt` and that's what the compiler complains about

It is also a bit strange to initialise a `@Binding` property since it is tied to a property from the parent view or some other value defined outside of the scope of the view so it's probably best to declare it as

```
@Binding var tappedItem: TabBarItem
```